# Why do Java applications require application servers to get hosted?

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat

While Apache http web server is also used for web hosting, why do many Java applications require a Tomcat or JBoss or Glassfish sort of environment for getting hosted?

Please provide the information, applications developed on what Java technologies can be hosted in Apache http web server. And when should we opt for an application server for hosting Java applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Java web applications, then they need to run Java code on the web server. A static web server alone won't do that.

That is the same situation with all other server-side programming environments as well (although some of them work via a plugin that is directly embedded into the Apache web server, you still need that plugin).

> applications developed on what java technologies can be hosted in Apache http web server

There is client-side Java (applets, Java web start). Probably not what you are talking about, but those run off a static web server.

For server-side Java, always use an application server or a standalone JVM (with an embedded server). Don't try to shove it into Apache (if that is even possible anymore these days). You may still want Apache (or nginx or something else) in addition as a front-end/load-balancer.

Comment: Lets imagine apache without php_module (is the different software module), add php to instalation. Then imagine tomcat (general: servlet container) like such module. In Java philosophy container give many additional highly standardised services to application (non existing or non standardised in php world) so environment seems big.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tomcat, otherwise known as “Tomcat” is a servlet container,  developed and maintained by the Apache Software Foundation. It is a Java implementation that runs Java Servlets and JavaServer Pages, known as JSPs.

Apache as a web server can be configured in many different ways and with many extensions, but it does lack the ability to serve Java Servelets or JavaServer Pages (hereafter referred to as JSP). Tomcat can and does serve those, and often people who use or need JSP will believe that Tomcat needs to be used to serve these .
The big downside for Apache is the lack of functionality for Java Servlets or JavaServer Pages, which cannot be run with Apache’s web server. Tomcat was created to address this problem.

Have a look here [Apache vs Tomcat](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1332518485-Tomcat-vs-Apache%3A-Why-One-Over-the-Other-) also [here](http://www.learncomputer.com/tomcat-vs-apache/)

Comment: Tomcat is a "servlet container", its module "coyote" ist a web server.

Comment: +1 @Stefan thnx, its an addition to my knowledge, if you feel to edit the sentences for clearity it would be worthfull